# How to add more inputs in a form inside <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form inside the script tags and I would love to add more input fields before I submit. My submit button does not work and i think it a pblem with how am accessing the submit button when I try this.

below is my form inside the script tags

```
<script defer type="text/html" id="template-RegisterView">

<div class="modal">

    <div class="signup-popup  pwd ">
        <div class="title">Sign up now</div>
        <p>and we'll find your right geek!</p>
        <form id="signup-form" action="bin/request/best.php" method="post">
           <input class="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" type="email">
           <input class="password" name="password" placeholder="Create password" type="password">

           <button class="signup-submit submitDialog" type="button">Sign up</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the script I want to use to add more input fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on('click', '.signup-submit', function () {
            $("#signup-form").submit( function(eventObj) {
                alert("fwf");
                  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                      .attr('name', "something")
                      .attr('value', "something")
                      .appendTo('#signup-form');
                  return true;
              });

         });
</script>
```

Comment: What functionality are you expecting on submit? Should the new input field be added and the form submitted?

Comment: Submit and append new input? no make any sense.. / inside `<script>` tag more.

Comment: @nipuna777 yes thats what i need this is because the inputs come from the outer html

Comment: @pedram yes the inputs are dynamic the only problem i have is accessing the form with the submit action

Comment: @pedram please check the updated code

Answer (score 2):

Rather than return true add `$("#signup-form").submit();`

**Further explanation**

The current code that you have is doing the following.

`$(document).on('click', '.signup-submit', function () {`

1. The above line means when click event occurs on the button with the signup-submit class, then execute the function that is provided as the third argument to the `$(document).on` method.
2. When the function is executed it executes the following lines

   `$("#signup-form").submit( function(eventObj) {
     alert("fwf");
     $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
       .attr('name', "something")
       .attr('value', "something")
       .appendTo('#signup-form');
     return true;
   });`
3. These lines are actually **defining or attaching** a function when the submit event will occur for form with id `signup-form`.
4. But they are not actually triggering the submit event.
5. To trigger the submit event you have write `$("#signup-form").submit();` without anything within `()`. That will trigger the submit event on the form.

You can check further details on this [link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). Its the official document explaining the usage of submit to attach a handler function or if you want to trigger the submit event for a form then how to do that.

Comment: There is a problem defined. There is an answer to it that solves the issue. The problem at hand and the problem context is something the asker knows about. If you have a better answer please provide that, that will in effect provide value to the readers. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for edit. I m actually using it on cell. Waiting in the car. 

Comment: The first problem with your post was unwrapped code *that edited*. Second you need write more explanation. But not expected when you use cell phone.. ;)

Comment: Ok. Will do when on machine. Thanks.

Comment: hey @muasif80 i did update the question please check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
var Param=//input parametr
var form = $("#signup-form");
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Param");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", Param);
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
form.submit();
```